# 80s or 90s anime with a robot chasing a girl in a flying craft

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's an anime probably from the 80-90s. I remember a long scene where a big robot that throws metal? balls from his arms is chasing a girl in a spaceship or glider on a desert planet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This could really use some more details.  Please check out [these suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: A girl flying on a glider over a desert immediately makes me think of Nausicaa of the Valley of the wind but the robot does not fit at all....

Answer (score 2):

Genmu Senki Leda, also known as "[Leda, the fantastic adventures of Yohko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leda:_The_Fantastic_Adventure_of_Yohko)"?

Giant robot throwing balls in the desert planet? Check.

80s-90s? The movie came out in 1985.

"girl in a spaceship or glider" A huge part of the movie is Yohko riding a glider around and escaping/fighting different robots. Most of which have round and ball-like bodies.

Comment: Thank you, Im going to check it now